# Shared calendar entry "locked for editing"

Tags: calendar, sharepoint-calendar

When using a shared calendar, does a calendar entry become "locked for editing" just like a word or excel document? Currently we use Outlook, however we are having an issue where two people have an entry open at the same time and whoever saves first loses all of the work when the second person saves.

Comment: have you resolved this issue? i'm currently having the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is **not possible to checkout a calendar entry** (I hope that is what you mean with "locked for editing").

Unfortunately I couldn't find any official statements from Microsoft or SharePoint MVPs where that was explicitly confirmed. My answer is thus based on the method of elimination as can be seen below:

1. Checkout isn't offered by default
2. in the Calendar List settings --> Versioning settings there is no possibility to enforce checkout for editing as it is possible in document libraries
3. there is no site or site collection feature I know that has to be activated for the checkout function
4. Microsoft only delivers documentation [how to check in / check out **a file**](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-server-help/check-out-check-in-or-discard-changes-to-files-in-a-site-library-HA101849698.aspx), no mentions about list items or calendar entries